# Iterate over pairs of columns and add value from one under condition in new column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with steps/action in user behaviour. Sample is provided. There are many steps. Each step contains two columns: subtitle and dimension.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'idVisit': [1, 2, 3],
                   'subtitle (step 0)': ['download', 'homepage', 'www.example.com'],
                   'dimension1 (step 0)': ['client', nan, 'internal'],
                   'subtitle (step 1)': ['pageview', 'pageview', 'map'],
                   'dimension1 (step 1)': ['client', 'client', nan],
                   'subtitle (step 2)': ['download', 'homepage', 'www.example.com'],
                   'dimension1 (step 2)': ['client', nan, 'internal'],
                   'subtitle (step 3)': ['pageview', 'pageview', 'map'],
                   'dimension1 (step 3)': ['client', 'client', nan]}
```

I need to merge columns subtitle and dimension for each step new column - if dimension is empty then keep only subtitle, if not keep only dimension. [image: table]

So new column step0 value: if df['dimension1 (step0)'] not null value then use df['dimension1 (step0)]
if df['dimension 1 (step0)] is null then use df['subtitle (step0)']
then repeated for step1.

I am complete newbie.

Expected output:

```py
[In]: df['step0'] 

[Out]: ['client', 'homepage', 'internal']

[In]: df['step1'] 

[Out]: ['client', 'client', 'map']

# etc.
```

Comment: Is your "dataframe" already a matrix? You may need to post some actual data or actual code.  If you have a matrix you can index through the data and then use if and elif statements to create a new data set.  Then output that to a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `idVisit` is the index. Then you may try `.combine_first()` method on every odd column (`dimension`) with every even one (`subtitle`):

```py
# set the index just in case
df.set_index('idVisit', inplace=True)
# loop over subtitles and dimensions zipped together and enumerated
for n, (subtitle, dimension) in enumerate(zip(df.columns[0::2], df.columns[1::2])):
    df[f'step {n}'] = df[dimension].combine_first(df[subtitle])
# show only added columns
df.iloc[:, 8:]
```

Output:

```py
# only the added columns are shown 
          step 0    step 1   step 2     step 3
idVisit             
1         client    client   client     client
2         homepage  client   homepage   client
3         internal  map      internal   map
```

Comment: Unfortunately, idVisit was not set as index and I'm getting subtitles in steps

Comment: @Beginnerinthehouse then you may just move the indices in the for loop by one: `enumerate(zip(df.columns[1::2], df.columns[2::2]))` and then `df.iloc[:, 9:]` or set `idVisit` as index before the loop: `df.set_index('idVisit', inplace=True)`

Comment: that's it, thank you very much! I was so in the panic mode,this is huge relief

Comment: @Beginnerinthehouse I added these steps to the answer. Glad to be of help, best of luck!